# How to present a 'launch view' modally before all other views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my tabbar based application, I need to present a 'launch view' who plays a role like a launch image. It contains a scroll view which displays several images. As it doesn't belong to the main tabbar based architecture, I'd like to present it modally.

Now my question is where to launch it. I run the `[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:launchViewController animated:YES];` after the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` inside the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

It works, but the main tab bar views will appear shortly before the 'launch view' appears. I need the 'launch view' to display before all other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present it modally in

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

of your root view controller.

Also present it without animation - it will prevent showing tab bar for a short time.

```
[self presentModalViewController:launchViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: The root view controller in my case is a UITabBarController, need I subclass it to define the viewDidAppear method?

Comment: Your tab bar controller has to have some view controller inside. One of them will be presented at first. Add showing of modal into first tab view controller viewDidAppear.

Your way is good too, but you have to set animated: to NO. If you present modal view with animation, transition style is used. Animated transition shows first view before the second - this is the reason tab bar view appear shortly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. When I add presentation of modal view to the viewDidAppear method of the view controller inside the fist tab bar item, when I dismiss the modal view, the modal view will appear again and again. I also tried to subclass a UITabBarController to customize the viewDidLoad method, and let it become the rootViewController of the window, but it's not invoked.

Comment: Usually you want to present "lauch view" only once. I usually create BOOL flag, like `BOOL showStartScreen;` and after first presentation I set that to NO. In viewDidAppear I check this flag.
About subclassing UITabBarController - documentation sais: _This class is not intended for subclassing._ It can make some troubles.

Comment: Sometimes, (and it seems to happen only on iOS 5, as opposed to 6), I see a short flicker of my initial view. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: What I did was in viewWillAppear on the underlying view, I checked if onboarding is needed, and if so, I add a UIView covering the whole view controller view.  Since the transition is so quick, it might be fine to just use a solid-colored view with the same color as the launch screen, or the same color as your presented modal view (or even the content of your launch screen...)  Just something that won't interrupt visual flow.  Then, I remove the cover view in the completion block of presentViewController for the modal view.